# how to make inner join without relation in django orm?

Tags: python, django, model

This is my first model

```
class DataPribadiSiswa(models.Model):
    SiswaID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    WaliKelasID = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    SiswaNIS = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

and this is my second model

```
class Transaksi(models.Model):
    tanggal = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    keterangan = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nominal = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nis = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)
```

how to make inner join query from that model without relation from those models where `DataPribadiSiswa.Siswanis` same with `Transaksi.nis`.

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Did you find the solution?